# Word for inbound or outbound?

Tags: sql, email, networking

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'm creating a SQL table that stores email history, and I need to name a column that indicates whether the email was inbound or outbound / incoming or outgoing / sent or received.

Is there a word for this in computer science, computer engineering, or networking?

Flow? Direction? Transmission mode? Transmission direction? These words do not seem to fit in this situation? or do they?

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you create a BOOLEAN, you'd call it inbound, incoming, or received.  In other words, name it after what TRUE represents.

Comment: I call it "direction". We developed a similar application a couple of years ago and we needed just that column. Since DB2 does not have boolean we used a SMALLINT with values 0 or 1.